# how to save CustomUser model to another model data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

here is my code at users/admin.py,

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from store.models import Customer

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm

CustomUser = get_user_model()

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser

    list_display = ['email', 'username',]


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Also users/forms.py code is,

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username',)

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username',)
```

I have table on store/models.py ,

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,unique=True)
    #name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Now can anyone please suggest me how to create a customer instances in user/admins.py or how to save data to customer table.